# Show that $f(x+\alpha h) - f(x) = 1/2(H(x)\alpha h, \alpha h) + o(\alpha^2), h \in \mathbb{R}^n, \alpha > 0$ where $H(x)$ is the hessian of $f(x)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, hessian-matrix

Show that $f(x+\alpha h) - f(x) = 1/2(H(x)\alpha h, \alpha h) + o(\alpha^2), h \in \mathbb{R}^n, \alpha > 0$ where $H(x)$ is the hessian of $f(x)$. Edit: also $\nabla f(x) = 0$. I can show that $f(x+\alpha h) - f(x) = (\nabla f(x), \alpha h) + o(\alpha)$. But I'm not sure where to go from here. Any hints?

Comment: Maybe you miss a condition $\nabla f(x)=0$? As the problem stated, what you want to prove is not correct. For instance, take $n=1$ and $f(x)=x$.

Comment: @Feng oh yes! I completely missed that part. But even so I'm not sure how to proceed

Comment: Consider the function $g(\alpha)=f(x+\alpha h)-f(x)$. Expand $g$ to the second order using Taylor's theorem.  Indeed, this is how we prove the [Taylor's theorem for multivariate functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Taylor's_theorem_for_multivariate_functions), and your situation is just a special case.

Comment: @Feng amazing! Thank you